# Python float and int behavior

Tags: python, floating-point-conversion

when i try to check whether float variable contain exact integer value i get the folowing strange behaviour.
My code :

```
x = 1.7  print x,  (x == int(x))   
x += 0.1  print x,  (x == int(x))
x += 0.1  print x,  (x == int(x))
x += 0.1  print x,  (x == int(x))
print "----------------------"

x = **2.7** print x,  (x == int(x))
x += 0.1  print x,  (x == int(x))
x += 0.1  print x,  (x == int(x))
x += 0.1  print x,  (x == int(x))
```

I get the folowing strange output (last line is the problem):

```
1.7 False
1.8 False
1.9 False
2.0 True
----------------------
2.7 False
2.8 False
2.9 False
3.0 False
```

Any idea why `2.0` is `true` and `3.0` is `false` ?

Comment: [This is relevant reading from the docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/995714). http://floating-point-gui.de/, [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 10):

the problem is not with conversion but with **addition**.

```
int(3.0) == 3.0
```

returns **True**

as expected.

The probelm is that floating points are not infinitely accurate, and you cannot expect 2.7 + 0.1 * 3 to be 3.0

```
>>> 2.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
3.0000000000000004
>>> 2.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 == 3.0
False
```

As suggested  by @SuperBiasedMan it is worth noting that in OPs approach the problem was somehow hidden due to the use of printing (string conversion) which simplifies data representation to maximize readability

```
>>> print 2.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 
3.0
>>> str(2.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1)
'3.0'
>>> repr(2.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1)
'3.0000000000000004'
```

Comment: Worth noting that the distinction isn't shown clearly because `print` will ignore the discrepancy for the sake of readability but if you were to use `repr(2.7 + 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1)` it would show the true value.

Comment: **Correction** A more accurate value, it will still ignore a certain number of decimal places.